# Creating a WebStorm search template for finding inappropriate use of ES6 string literal syntax in normal string literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

What I'm trying to do is set up a warning so that if I ever have something like this in my code `'foo bar quax ${ldsfjal}'` I get a warning because I'm using the ' character instead of the ` to create my string.

How can I create a search template in WebStorm to identify these situations?

Comment: You mean like http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes?

Comment: No because in my workflow I use single quotes for string literals if there are no variables that need to get appended.